# AWS | How to Register EC2 instance on ELBV2 from lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, nlb

I am a newbie on AWS, I am able to register EC2 instance through the target groups on Network Load Balancer. I deployed 4 different services on EC2 instance with different port and registered each service with its port i.e. 8081,8082 etc on the network load balancer. But I am getting a few problems,

**Problem:**

1. EC2 Instances are getting de-register automatically from the target group for only one service i.e. 8081. Why its getting deregister automatically?

I go through the AWS documentation and different blogs but I don't get any specific reason why EC2 instance are getting removed from Network load balancers target group automatically even same instances for other services are not removing from the target group.

**Solution:**
Now Finally, I am created one cloud watch alarm, if any EC2 instance gets removed it should trigger one notification email and also trigger lambda function to register EC2 instance again.

**Problem:**

1. I am not able to register from Lambda. How can I register through Lambda function?

can anyone please help me on the above questions or if any alternate best solution to achieve above-mentioned use case.

Thanks,

Comment: So, are you asking how to add an Amazon EC2 instance to a Target Group from AWS Lambda? If so, which language are you using?

Comment: yes, I am open to any language but python is preferable

Answer (score 2):

You would use [`register_targets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.register_targets):

> Registers the specified targets with the specified target group.
>
> If the target is an EC2 instance, it must be in the running state when you register it.

```
response = client.register_targets(
    TargetGroupArn='arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-targets/73e2d6bc24d8a067',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Id': 'i-abcd1234',
            'Port': 80
        },
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code where you can use register targets in target groups. The below code is running under python 2.7

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('elbv2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event
    }

    response = client.register_targets(
    TargetGroupArn='<add_your_target_ARN_here>',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Id': 'inctance_ID',
            'Port': <port>
        },
    ]
)
    
    return response
```